# Stanford iphone development tutorial fail. Why is my code crashing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I tried following the Stanford iphone development tutorial and I got stuck because my iPhone app is crashing.   Help!

Error message

> 2013-03-03 12:10:39.055 RPN Calculator[2166:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key digitPressed.

Header

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
@interface CalculatorViewController ()
@end
@implementation CalculatorViewController

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
      NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
      NSLog(@"Digit pressed = %@", digit);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably created an `IBOutlet` `digitPressed` instead of an `IBAction`. So realizing this, deleted the code from your .h and .m file. But forgot to remove the connection from .xib (happened to me also when I started off). If that is the case, you can right click on your button for which the `IBAction` is called and delete the connection.

Answer (score 2):

your problem might be that your action method  `digitPresses` is not assigned properly with the `UIButton` defined in your `.xib` or storyboard  and it is missing the link defined in your code, you could check that it in the connection inspector and make sure you are connecting the action with the `touch up inside` event